# Use ngFor in a Table inside of ng-template

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-template

I'm trying to iterate though a list, which I get from an API-request, and insert the data into a table. My problem is, that this table is inside of a **ng-template** tag and I don't know how to deal with this.

This is my code:

```html
<ng-template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Reference</th>
        <th>Chapter</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let ref of data">
        <td>{{ref.title}}</td>
        <td>{{ref.chapter}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</ng-template>
```

And this is my goal:
[Popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zgmb.png)

Comment: Why is it inside an `ng-template`?

Comment: Because, it's ment to be in a popover

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution for your issue:

[image]

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Reference</th>
      <th>Chapter</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-template ngFor let-ref [ngForOf]="data">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ref.title}}</td>
        <td>{{ref.chapter}}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and the typescript code:

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  data = [
    {
      title: "title 1",
      chapter: "chapter1"
    },
    {
      title: "title 2",
      chapter: "chapter2"
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: You may add the code directly instead of adding a screenshot.

Comment: I added the source code you can check it .

Comment: In this example only the tr is inside of the ng-template. But my question is, would it also be possible, that the whole table is inside of the ng-template?

Answer (score 1):

If you has a variable "yourVariable"

In general you can have a

```
<ng-template #template1>
.... e.g. {{yourVariable|json}}..
</ng-template>
```

And use

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template1"></ng-container>
```

You can also using

```
<ng-template #template2 let-data >
.... e.g. {{data|json}}..
</ng-template>
```

and you indicate in *ngTemplateOutlet the "context"

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template2; context:{$implicit:yourVariable}">
</ng-container>
```

See that, in this case inside the template "data" is "you variable"

I don't know about your "popover" but sure you need a "template reference variable" to your template (the "#template1" and "#template2" in the code above)